# Beautiful Soup/ Selenium web scraping

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get a product name and its price from one local website.

The website is loaded dynamically, therefore requests doesn't support it. I am using Selenium and Beautiful Soup.

However it double counts each product ( I get 2 links for the same product), is there any solution for this?

Also, after getting product links I need to get product information (e.g, Name and Price), but again it double counts products and don't get the name and price.

My code:

```
import pandas as pd        
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    
productlinks = []
baseurl = "https://www.technodom.kz/"
options = Options()
options.headless = True

driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\path\to\chromedriver.exe", options=options)


for x in range(1, 5):
    driver.get(
        f"https://www.technodom.kz/bytovaja-tehnika/uhod-za-odezhdoj/stiral-nye-mashiny/f/brands/lg/brands/samsung?page={x}"
    )
    # Wait for the page to fully render
    sleep(3)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "lxml")
    product_list = soup.find_all("li", class_="ProductCard")
    for item in product_list:
        for link in item.find_all("a", href=True):
            productlinks.append(baseurl + link["href"])
    print(productlinks)

wmlist = []
for link in productlinks:
    driver.get(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "lxml")
    print(link)
    name = soup.find('h1', class_='ProductHeader-Title').text.strip()
    price = soup.find('p', class_='ProductPrice ProductInformation-Price').text.strip()

    wm = {
        'Model':name,
        'Price': price
    }
    wmlist.append(wm)
    print('Saving:', wm['Model'])
df = pd.DataFrame(wmlist)

df.to_excel("TD pricesTEST.xlsx", sheet_name='TEW', index=False)
```

Comment: `productlinks` is undefined and you're using `pandas` but there's no import.

Comment: productlinks probably should be product_links. Also item.find_all("a", href=True) will return the same URL multiple times because it is the HTML! You can either target the correct a tag or check url is unique with an IF statement before append.

Comment: Actually productlinks is defined and I imported pandas, added in the code.

Answer (score 1):

Those nested loops are to be blamed for doubling your output. Also, all you need is in one `<a>` tag with the class of `ProductCard-Content`.

I've simplified your code a bit and here's how you can get product names, prices, and links and finally dump them to an Excel file:

```
from time import sleep

import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.headless = True
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

final_output = []
pages = list(range(1, 5))

for page_number in pages:
    print(f"Scraping page: {page_number} / {len(pages)}")
    driver.get(
        f"https://www.technodom.kz/bytovaja-tehnika/uhod-za-odezhdoj/"
        f"stiral-nye-mashiny/f/brands/lg/brands/samsung?page={page_number}"
    )
    sleep(5)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(
        driver.page_source,
        "lxml",
    ).find_all("a", class_="ProductCard-Content")

    links = [f"https://www.technodom.kz/{anchor['href']}" for anchor in soup]
    names = [name.find("h4").getText() for name in soup]
    prices = [price.find("data")["value"] for price in soup]

    final_output.append(
        [
            [name, price, link] for name, price, link
            in zip(names, prices, links)
        ]
    )

df = pd.DataFrame(
    [data for sub_list in final_output for data in sub_list],
    columns=["NAME", "PRICE", "LINK"],
)
df.to_excel("test.xlsx", sheet_name='TEW', index=False)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Hello, thank you for the comment, however I noticed that the code downloads only first page, 24 models.

Comment: Still not getting all data, total products in excel sheet is 49, but in website it is 85

Comment: It seems that its not enough time to render a page so I increased sleep time to 5 second and now it is working.

Comment: Well, I can't reproduce this as I get an Excel file with 85 (header included). Make sure you have the right values here `range(1, 5)` and let the script do a full run.

Comment: Then if it's working consider up-voting and/or accepting the answer.

Comment: Could you please check if you have duplicates values in your excel. I have 12 duplicates

Comment: No, I don't have any duplicates. If there are any, then it's the site, not the code itself.